# Div within a div still taking up space even though display:none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select#choosebook").change(function(){
    $(".title").slideDown("medium");
});
</head>

<body>
<div class="booktitle">
    <p>
    <font color="red">*</font>Book:
    <select id="choosebook">
        <option>Choose a Book...</option>
        <option>Add new Book...</option>
    </select>
    <div class="title" style="display:none">**
        <font color="red">*</font>Title: <input type="text">
    </div>
    <font color="red">*</font>Page: <input type="text" class="page">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div with class "title" still takes up space between the "Book:" input and the "Page:" input, even though it's hidden! Other divs on this web page don't. How can I make it take up no space until the javascript is activated to slide it down?

Thank you!

EDIT: As requested, here is a screenshot of the problem. I'm trying to get rid of the gap between the Book input and the Title input.
Before the 'title' input slides down:
[image: The stupid gap before the 'title' input slides down.]
After the 'title' input slides down:
[image: The stupid gap after the 'title' input slides down.]

And here is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url("layout.css");
    .page {
        width: 50px;
    }
    .URL, .booktitle {
        margin-left: 24px;
        display:none;
    }
    .title {
        display: none;
    }
    .newtag {
        display:none;
    }
    .amount, .addtag {
        width: 100px;
    }
    .details {
        width: 275px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: have you tried with "visibility: hidden"?

Comment: perhaps not the solution, but try closing your input tags.

Comment: @Teddy: Doesn't work; it still takes up space, and that makes it even worse because then when the javascript slides down the div, the text and input are invisible!

Comment: @11684 they are closed??

Comment: He means `<input type="text" />`, but it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Oh I see. I added that to my <input> tags but it still didn't solve the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: @Juhana sometimes (in some browsers) it does matter, mostly with the layout.

Comment: @torjinx, the HTML you have put up doesn't seem to have a doctype specified. Have you tried adding a doctype? For HTML5 you would use `<!doctype html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the huge space under the Book drop down then that is because of the `p` tag that you have open in the HTML but forgot to close it. The `p` tag is adding the default margin. Hence the space. Remove the `p` tag and the margin should go away.

Also as I mentioned in the comments to your question always add a `doctype` to you page.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle without the P tag, it does still not work for him.

Comment: Without the `p` tag it definitely should work unless they are looking at some other space that is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @torjinx, glad to help. Allan's answer below was correct as well since he removed the `p` tag in the HTML provided.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the div that's creating the space, it's the `<br>` you have right after it.

And please, get rid of the `<font>` tags. My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: lol. I'll get on that. Thanks for pointing out the <br> tag, it was there from before I added the 'title' div. However, I got rid of it and there is still a mysterious space between the <select> list and the 'title' div. I can't figure out why??

Answer (score 0):

The font element is deprecated, use span here. You did not close your script element.

I cleaned up a bit and now you got this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select#choosebook").change(function(){
    $(".title").slideDown("medium");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="booktitle">
    <span style="color:red">*</span>Book:
    <select id="choosebook">
        <option>Choose a Book...</option>
        <option>Add new Book...</option>
    </select>
    <div class="title" style="display:none">
        <span style="color:red">*</span>
        Title: <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <span style="color:red">*</span>
    Page: <input type="text" class="page">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/cJ6Jq/ works for me.

Comment: I had closed the script tag in my html, I just forgot to add that here. I made all the changes you suggested but it still didn't solve my problem. Thanks for helping me clean it up though. :)

Comment: Can you provide me some screenshots? And are you using any CSS on the page? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using CSS. Browser is Chrome. How do I give you screenshots? Sorry I'm pretty new to this site!

Comment: Paste the CSS so we can see it. You can upload them to imgur.com and post the link, or just edit the original post and upload them there.